# Cannot find element before timeout ends

Tags: c#, automation, appium

I'm creating simple test automation project using appium, C#. its opening app correctly and after that code cannot click on the element. and show exception
**"OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/34e0ca2f-af1f-48ef-aafe-d6a46516a862/element timed out after 60 seconds.'"**

[Image of the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzYif.png)

i have tried changing the xpath and driver types

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Interfaces;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace FlowLogic_Test_Project
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        AppiumDriver<IWebElement> driver;

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
            capabilities.SetCapability("appActivity", ".MainActivity");
            capabilities.SetCapability("appPackage", "com.flowlogicclient");
            capabilities.SetCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator1");

            //Launch the Android driver
            driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            driver.FindElementByXPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[2]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[2]/android.view.ViewGroup").Click();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure about this [`UiAutomator1` capability](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/android-uiautomator/index.html)? If your emulator is running Android 5.1 [API level 22](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms#5.1) or higher you **must** use [UIAutomator2](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/android-uiautomator2/index.html) otherwise you will not be able to proceed further than application launch.

You could also reconsider the [locator strategy](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#locator-strategies) as the preferred way of locating elements on Android is using `resource-id`. Or at least you could use relative XPath, not starting from `<hierarchy>` tag but rather uniquely identifying your element using its tag value or text.

Going forward avoid using Thread.sleep as it's some form of performance anti-pattern, there is [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) class along with [DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers/) providing APIs to wait for elements presence/visibility/clickability/absence/etc. Check out [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) article to get familiarized with the concept

Comment: thanx a lot for your solution. the problem was i used "UiAutomator1". as per your solution i have changed it to "UIAutomator2" . now its selecting elements correctly. thank you again..